# insert multiple input box on multiple loop to database and remove empty array

Tags: javascript, php, html, loops

I have 2 problem here

1. I have to remove array which it value is 0
2. I have to insert a data to database using loop

any response would be appreciated

here my code :

Javascript

```
for (a = 0; a <= i; a++) {
  $(".addmore_" + a).on('click', function (a) {
    return function() {

      var data = "<tr><td><input class='form-control sedang' type='text' id='packinglist_" + a + "' name='packinglist[]'/></td></tr>";
      $("#keatas_" + a).append(data);
    } ;
  } 
  (a));
};
```

My Java script is working properly but the point is when I want to add the input-box to database, a data didn't loop

here my html

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
    <table id='keatas_$i' class='keatas'>
        <tr>
            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='hiddenlot_$i' name='hiddenlot[]' />
            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' id='hiddencustomer_$i' name='hiddencustomer[]' />
            <td>
              <a><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-plus addmore_$i'></span></a> 
            </td>
        </tr>                                   
    </table>
}
```

so i need to loop my input box everytime i press "addmore" button ,and for some reason i need to loop `'hiddencustomer[]' and 'hiddenlot[]'`

and here my **query.php**

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
    $idlot = $_POST['hiddenlot'][$i];
    $customer = $_POST['hiddencustomer'][$i];
    $a=mysql_query("INSERT INTO item VALUES ('',now(),'$idlot')");
    $count = count($_POST['packinglist']);

    for ($c = 0; $c < $count; $c++) {
        $pack = $_POST['packinglist'];
        $packinglist1 = array_values(array_filter($pack));
        $packinglist = $packinglist1[$c];
        $item = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM item ORDER BY item_id DESC");
        $itemid = mysql_fetch_array($item);
        $a= mysql_query("INSERT INTO packing_list VALUES('','$packinglist','$itemid[item_id]')");
    }
}
```

I put 2nd loop in 1st loop cause I need a `item_id` for insert to packing_list table and I got a item_id by last input to item table

sorry for bad explain and bad english
I hope you can understand what I mean
thankyou

Comment: Uh, You can't mix and match html / php like you are doing in your html file... - Also, you have a syntax error at the end of your first `mysql_query`, you need to add a missing `"` at the end. (Look at the color coding)

Comment: You have an error in this line. `$a=mysql_query("INSERT INTO item VALUES ('',now(),'$idlot');`. Change it to `$a=mysql_query("INSERT INTO item VALUES ('',now(),'$idlot')");` *Just saying*

Comment: umm , yeah it's right , but its not my full code , i just cut the point of the problem so you can read it more easier , but in my full code it working propely . so my problem is how to add data to database when i use double looping and array